# Is it possible to count multiple text occurrences within ONE cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I've got the words `Won`, `Lost`, and `Tied` all in one cell, is there a formula that would be able to count the number of times `Lost` and `Tied` appear within the cell?

I've come across a formula that uses `LEN` and `SUBSTITUTE` and works great for counting the occurrence of a single string of text in a cell but not for multiple strings of text.

Here is the formula I have for context,

```
=(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"Lost",)))/LEN("Lost")
```

Tried adding "Tied" to the formula but doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: It should work - are you doing it seperately 
=(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"Lost",)))/LEN("Lost") +(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"View",)))/LEN("View") ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
 =(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"Lost",)))/LEN("Lost") +(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"Tied",)))/LEN("Tied")
(LEN(V5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V5,"Won",)))/LEN("Won")
```